# How to make Maven install submodule poms?

Tags: maven-3, nexus

I have a project that is building fine on my laptop.  Today I started to set up the build for this on our Bamboo server.  Everything is checked in.  Both my laptop and the build server are using Maven 3.0.4.

I have a top-level aggregator pom that specifies several modules, but this pom is not the parent of any module.  I do use parent poms, but those parents are in peer submodules of the submodules that depend on them, and I have blank "relativePath" elements in all poms.

In the Bamboo build of the top-level aggregator POM, I see several errors like this:

[ERROR]   The project com.example.cde:java-project-parent:1.0.1 (/volatile/bamboo/bamboo3.4.3_data/xml-data/build-dir/FOO-BUILD-JOB1/java-project-parent/pom.xml) has 1 error
18-Dec-2012 16:40:21    [ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find com.example.cde:project-parent:pom:1.0.0 in http://hostname.net:8081/nexus/content/groups/stuff was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 6, column 11 -> [Help 2]

The "java-project-parent" is one of the poms in the parent hierarchy.

What I've discovered is that running "mvn install" in the top-level aggregator pom isn't actually installing the artifacts in the submodules. When I looked in the local repo, the only thing in each directory in the local repo was a file like "...pom.lastUpdated".   The actual POM wasn't there.

When I had the admin manually run "mvn install" in the first submodule, that actually installed the POM into the local repo.  I have a feeling if he manually installs the other two parent poms, the build of the project that depends on all three of them will build fine.

I must be misunderstanding an important detail of how a build with submodules works.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

run maven clean install with Force update option as below:

> mvn clean install -U

Answer (score 0):

Your hierarchy is probably broken. You can test that by building it in your local machine after wiping the local repository. Most likely you will find the same failures as on the build machine.

To fix it I would suggest remove all the relative path elements and adjust the structure so a build will work fine. Ideally you even break the pure parent projects out into separate projects and release them into your repository manager so that any other builds get them from there..

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a mvn -U install to force a mvn trip to your nexus repo for updated aritfacts
Also run mvn with the -e switch to see detailed error messages